# Installation - Moodle 3.5.2+ (Build: 20181103) Error

Tags: mysql, installation, moodle, privileges

I am trying to instal Moodle 3.5.2+ on my host using cpanel; however, after creating the database, I get the following error: 
[Moodle Installation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hswSf.png)

Then I try using these SQL commands and this gives me another one #1227:

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format = barracuda
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table = 1
SET GLOBAL innodb_large_prefix = 'on'
```

[MySQL error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12udh.png)

I don't seem to be able to have access to change any privileges on my cpanel.
 Note: I am using a shared web server.

Can anyone please help me?

[My phpAdmin Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PRVS.png)

Comment: Can you check the privileges you have with that account you used to log in to phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
This basically seems to be the problem! I can't find it! 
I have attached a new photo to the post showing my phpAdmin area.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that cPanel and/or the provider of your shared webserver restricts the privileges of your database user.

I can see two options here that you could take:

- Get the required privileges from cPanel/the provider of the webserver (unlikely, but may be worth a shot)
- Get a VPS server and spin up a MySQL server on your own

The second option also gives you the possibility of creating other databases according to your need.